# SQL to query fixed timeframe from current year using a text field number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a text field that has dates in this format:
`20020807; 20150806; 20161025` .

What I need to do is run sql to gather the current system year and gather the first 4 digits of this text field above (which gets us a year value) and select all of the records that have a year value within the past 3 years.
So with the above 3 examples, the results would return the last 2 records only.  Note this is an Oracle database.

I have a bit of sql that can gather specific values from the first 4 digits:
`SELECT * FROM customer_link WHERE SUBSTR(TEST_DATE, 1,4) IN ('2002')`.  Note I do not want to explicitly input years but dynamically query the past 3 years from the current year.

And a bit that gathers the current year: `SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY') FROM dual`

But need some help putting the pieces together.
Thank You!

Comment: What do you mean by "last three years"? Today is 20161109 (in your notation); "last three years" means anything in years 2014, 2015 and 2016, regardless of date? If it should be on or after 20131109 (the more common meaning of "last three years" measured from SYSDATE), you can't do that by just taking the YEAR from the current date. Please clarify the requirement. Also: What is that format - three dates separated by semicolon (;) all in one value (one row, one column)? Or were you showing three different values, from a column or similar?

Comment: Why are you storing delimited values in a single column? And why aren't you storing dates as proper dates?

Comment: "Last three years" means 3 years prior to the current date.  The semicolon was just to show the 3 dates.  They are not actually like this in the field. And yes, they should have been originally stored as dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, but expect full scans of your table:

```
select * from mytable
where substr(my_date, 1, 4) in (
  select to_char(to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')) - (level-1)) yr
  from dual
  connect by level <= 3);
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your suggestions, but the query should work just fine.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks again for your input.  Unless I'm missing something, I do convert to a number to subtract.  I do a final to_char for the subquery to return a list of strings, since thats what substr returns.  But since you're so adamant about it, perhaps you have a better solution that isn't so "sloppy"

Comment: This sql does seem to work for me.  Thank you tbone.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the answers to what I asked you in a Comment to your question, the better way to work with the data is to work with everything in the DATE data type.

For example, if `test_date` is an eight character string like `20140208` and you want all values that fall within three years from January 1, 2016, meaning all dates from January 1, 2013 till today, then you could use a WHERE clause like this:

```
... where to_date(test_date, 'yyyymmdd') between add_months(trunc(sysdate'y'), -36) 
                                         and     sysdate
```

`trunc(sysdate, 'y')` returns January 1 of the current year, and `add_months()` adds (or subtracts, if the second argument is negative) the indicated number of months. `add_years(..., -3)` would be good, too, but it **does not exist** in Oracle.

Comment: There is an "add_years()" function: `some_date + interval '-3' year`. It however has the same "bug" as any interval maths: it doesn't properly deal with leap years.